# ReferenceError: Oxygen is not defined

Tags: vercel, hydrogen, shopify-hydrogen

I am trying to deploy hydrogen based application using vercel.
I have selected `Framework Preset` as hydrogen while creating project.
Error that I am getting is
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

And if i check log its saying

```
[GET] /
14:35:45:13
ReferenceError: Oxygen is not defined
    at worker.js:565:22163
    at worker.js:159:2014
    at worker.js:2388:12955
```

Any idea how to fix this?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZeq0.png

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing same issue. In `hydrogen.config.js` we are checking for Oxygen env. So removing that will fix this ( if you are deploying on non oxygen env )
After edit it will look like this

```
import {defineConfig, CookieSessionStorage} from '@shopify/hydrogen/config';

export default defineConfig({
  shopify: {
    defaultCountryCode: 'US',
    defaultLanguageCode: 'EN',
    storeDomain: 'xx.myshopify.com', // || Oxygen?.env?.PUBLIC_STORE_DOMAIN,
    storefrontToken: 'xxx', // Oxygen?.env?.PUBLIC_STOREFRONT_API_TOKEN,
    storefrontApiVersion: '2022-07',
  },
  session: CookieSessionStorage('__session', {
    path: '/',
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: import.meta.env.PROD,
    sameSite: 'Strict',
    maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 30,
  }),
});
```